# Returning field name when using Max and Count queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Cant seem to figure this one out...

I have a table, one of the fields is variabletype.  There are several user input variable types.  For example:

```
id | variabletype
 1 | button
 2 | text
 3 | button
 4 | link
 5 | button
 6 | link
```

I wrote some SQL to basically count the number of times each variable type is listed.  I nestled that into a subquery so that I can then get the record that has the max number of instances (in this example - button).

My problem is the query only returns the max number, it does not display the actual variable type.  my ideal outcome is having the variabletype display along with the max count.  Any thoughts?

```
 SELECT MAX(y.mosttested)
   FROM (SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variableid) AS mosttested
     FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype) y
```

Comment: Please post which SQL database & version you are using. There are a ton of SQL varieties and what works in one does not necessarily work in others.

Comment: @SashikanthDareddy mysql 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT `variabletype `,
       COUNT(`variabletype `) AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM   `my_table`
GROUP BY `value`
ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: @user2828701: you should be aware that this will give you "random" results as the usage of the `group by` operator in that query  is incorrect (but MySQL will let you do it anyway - unlike all other DBMS). To understand the implications of the "loose" `group by`, please read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: he can manipulate this statement as eleminating the group limiting ,which will return "static result" as he need

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select variabletype,n
from 
  (SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variableid) AS mosttested
  FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype) v 
where mosttested=(SELECT MAX(y.mosttested) AS n
   FROM (SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variableid) AS mosttested
     FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype) y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If row_number function is avialable in your SQL environment then you can do the following:

```
SELECT y.variabletype, y.mosttested as max_mosttested
   FROM (SELECT variabletype, COUNT(variableid) AS mosttested, row_number()over(order by count(variableid) desc)
     FROM variable GROUP BY variabletype) y
where rownum=1
```